# flutter doughnut chart has hugh margin/padding. how to remove?

Tags: flutter, dart

After i put the chart there is a high margin/padding.

How to I reduce the space between the chart? or put it to zero?

[image]

```
Center(
      child: Container(
        child: SfCircularChart(
          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
          annotations: <CircularChartAnnotation>[
            CircularChartAnnotation(
              widget: Container(
                child: Text(
                  rating.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                ),
              )
            )
          ],
          series: <CircularSeries>[
              DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
                  dataSource: [
                    ChartData('Score', rating.toDouble(), Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    ChartData('-Score', (100 - rating).toDouble(), Colors.grey.shade900)                           
                  ],
                  xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                  yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
                  pointColorMapper:(ChartData data,  _) => data.color,
                  radius: '50%',
                  innerRadius: '80%',
                  strokeColor: Colors.amber
              )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Have you found the answer? I also want to remove inner padding of SfCircularChart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a width and height for the container that hold all the chart widget.

```
Center(
  child: Container(

    // add here
    width: 100, // for example
    height: 100, // for example

    child: SfCircularChart(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
      annotations: <CircularChartAnnotation>[
        CircularChartAnnotation(
          widget: Container(
            child: Text(
              rating.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
            ),
          )
        )
      ],
      series: <CircularSeries>[
          DoughnutSeries<ChartData, String>(
              dataSource: [
                ChartData('Score', rating.toDouble(), Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ChartData('-Score', (100 - rating).toDouble(), Colors.grey.shade900)                           
              ],
              xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
              yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y,
              pointColorMapper:(ChartData data,  _) => data.color,
              radius: '50%',
              innerRadius: '80%',
              strokeColor: Colors.amber
          )
      ]
    )
  ),
);
```